# Change the Input text field value by keeping the original value

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

Is there a way I can assign a new value for an input text field but shows the original value in the input text. What I am asking is, Suppose user enter "john" in the input text which is a Struts2 text field which has the name as user login which binds to the User class in login property:

```
<s:textfield name="user.login" maxlength="20" size="20"/>
```

While submitting I want to change "john" into some encripted value and assign that value to the text field so that I can retrieve that value in Action class.

The problem is that when I add the below line to acheive it

```
document.getElementsByName("user.login")[0].value="johnnew887878";
```

, the user see his originally entered value changed. I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a hidden field when you submit the form and assign the encrypted value to the hidden field and append the field to the form and catch the encrypted value in your User class.

Comment: The problem here is then the non encripted user name and password also submiting with the form submition know. The whole idea of doing above is prevent user submit original credentials and submit the encripted values instead

Comment: You can set the value of name and password field to blank and send the encrypt value through hidden fields. This feature also have flaws because hackers can read the password in the encrypted values and tries to decrypt it. Best option is to create a server token key and store that key in hidden field and match the key in the server and also this key is valid only for few minutes or seconds. And also create password salt on server. Concatenate that salt to password and store in DB. And while matching the password concatenate that key to password and match it.

Comment: yes i am currently doing similar to what you proposed. I use JEncription for it. I first get server generated keys to the jsp and store them in a java script variable and then once user submit i encrypted username password with those keys and replace the user entered credentials with encrypted values (the problem is at this point where user can see his  enter values change) and then submit.This is struts2 environment i am using. But as you mentioned make them blank and submit the encrypted values in hidden variables is ok. But then again user will complain his values enter suddenly disappear